# Extract element from array depending on elements of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have a result set that could match any combination of this data structure:

```
[ ["1st", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "FELONY"],  ["3nd", "FELONY"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["3rd", "MISDEMEANOR"]]
```

So it could be something like this:

```
[  ["2nd", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"]]
```

Or this:

```
[ ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"]]
```

Or some other combination AND order of elements.

If the array has a subarray of FELONY, then I want to ignore MISDEMEANOR elements and just fetch "1st" if present, otherwise "2nd", otherwise "3rd".
Now if array does not contain FELONY elements, then I want to pull "1st" MISDEMEANOR element if present, otherwise "2nd", otherwise "3rd".

My solution:

```js
var arr = [ ["1st", "FELONY"], ["3nd", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["3rd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"]];
for(var i = 0, found = [], fel1 = false, fel2 = false, fel3 = false, mis1 = false, mis2 = false, mis3 = false; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i][0] == "1st" && arr[i][1] == "FELONY"){
       found = arr[i];
       fel1 = true;
   } else if (arr[i][0] == "2nd" && arr[i][1] == "FELONY" && !fel1){
       found = arr[i];
       fel2 = true;
   } else if (arr[i][0] == "3rd" && arr[i][1] == "FELONY" && !fel1 && !fel2){
       found = arr[i];
       fel3 = true;
   } else if (arr[i][0] == "1st" && arr[i][1] == "MISDEMEANOR" && !fel1 && !fel2 && !fel3){
       found = arr[i];
       mis1 = true;
   } else if (arr[i][0] == "2st" && arr[i][1] == "MISDEMEANOR" && !fel1 && !fel2 && !fel3 && !mis1){
       found = arr[i];
       mis2 = true;
   } else if (arr[i][0] == "3st" && arr[i][1] == "MISDEMEANOR" && !fel1 && !fel2 && !fel3 && !mis1){
       found = arr[i];
       mis3 = true;
   }
}


if( match && (match[2] == "FELONY" || match[2] == "MISDEMEANOR") && (found[2] != "FELONY" && found[1] != "1st") ) {
            found = [ match[1], match[2], match[3], match[4] ]
            console.log("FOUND! " + found[1]);
} else {
            console.log(`could not parse ${chargesList[i]}`);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(found));
```

It gets the job done but a little sloppy. Is there a better way to do this with EcmaScript 6 functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you only want to go through your array once and if possible avoid a giant string of `if/else if`s. One way to do this would be to use a system that allows you to make unique scores for each item where the highest score is the item you want. There are many ways to do this, but one simple one is to assign numbers to `felony` and `misdemeanor` such that they are guaranteed to be larger the the second dimension. The felony/misdemeanors get the 10s place and the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, occupy the 1s place. Then you can look through your array once and find the highest score:

```js
let scores = {
  FELONY: 20,
  MISDEMEANOR: 10,
  '1st': 3,
  '2nd': 2,
  '3rd': 1
}

let arr = [["2nd", "FELONY"],["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"],["1st", "FELONY"]]

let highest = 0, result
for (item of arr) {
  let score = item.reduce((a, c) => a + scores[c], 0)
  if (score > highest) {
    highest = score
    result = item
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

This also makes it very easy to edit your preferences or add different categories and it doesn't depend on the alphabetical sorting order of your categories.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple version would be:

```
function mySort(a) {
  return [...a].sort(([aa, ab], [ba, bb]) => (ab + aa).localeCompare(bb + ba))
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const [selected] = mySort(arr)
```

A few things to note:

- We need `[...a]` to copy the array because `sort` mutates the array it operates on
- This only works because the `F` from `FELONY` comes before the `M` from `MISDEMEANOR` and your `1st`, `2nd` and `3rd` start with numbers
- This is not a performant way to do it, but in your case it is probably fine

If you do need other strings to sort you can use a lookup table:

```
const lookup = {
  FELONY: 1,
  MISDEMEANOR: 2,
  ...
}

sort(... => (lookup[ab] + lookup[aa]).localeCompare(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following is any more elegant and or better than what you have, (leave it up to the JS experts here to comment) but something you that i could come up with

The following **crude assumptions** were made though :-|

1. The first index of the inner array (sub array) always starts with numbers such as 1st, 2nd etc

   1.1 the letters that follow the number are single digits (not > 9).

```js
var sampleArray = [ ["1st", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "FELONY"],  ["3nd", "FELONY"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["3rd", "MISDEMEANOR"]] 
// var sampleArray = [["2nd", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"]]
// var sampleArray = [["2nd", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"]]
 
var reducedArray = sampleArray.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b))

// step 1 : to just filter felony if any.
let result = [];
if(reducedArray.includes("FELONY")) {
sampleArray.forEach(a => {if(a.includes("FELONY")) {
    result.push(a);
}})
}else{
result = sampleArray;
}

// step 2: sort and print first

result.sort((a,b) => {
if(a[0].substring(0) < b[0].substring(0)) {
    return -1;
} else if(a[0].substring(0) > b[0].substring(0)){
    return 1;
}
return 0;
})

console.log(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily convert your structure to object structure. Which will work for any number of person or ranking after wards.

```js
const list = [ ["1st", "FELONY"], ["2nd", "FELONY"],  ["3nd", "FELONY"], ["1st", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["3rd", "MISDEMEANOR"]]  

let obj = {}
list.forEach((item, index) => {
  obj = {
    ...obj,
    [item[1]] : {
       ...obj[item[1]],
       [item[0]]: index,
    }
  }
})

console.log(obj)
```

so you can see that for the list given above , our object looks something like

```
{
  "FELONY": {
    "1st": 0,
    "2nd": 1,
    "3nd": 2
  },
  "MISDEMEANOR": {
    "1st": 3,
    "3rd": 4
  }
}
```

for which now we can extract the needed value as

```js
const obj = {
  "FELONY": {
    "1st": 0,
    "2nd": 1,
    "3nd": 2
  },
  "MISDEMEANOR": {
    "1st": 3,
    "3rd": 4
  }
}

let nameToLookFor = 'FELONY';
if (!obj[nameToLookFor) {
  nameToLookFor = 'MISDEMEANOR'
}

const found = 
  obj[nameToLookFor]['1st'] || obj[nameToLookFor]['2nd'] || obj[nameToLookFor]['3rd']);

console.log(found)
```

```js
const obj = {
  "FELONY": {
    "1st": 0,
    "2nd": 1,
    "3nd": 2
  },
  "MISDEMEANOR": {
    "1st": 3,
    "3rd": 4
  }
}

let nameToLookFor = 'FELONY';
if (!obj[nameToLookFor]) {
  nameToLookFor = 'MISDEMEANOR'
}


const found = 
  obj[nameToLookFor]['1st'] || obj[nameToLookFor]['2nd'] || obj[nameToLookFor]['3rd'];

console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function penaltiesSort(data){
    const   felonies = data.filter(subArr => subArr[1] == "FELONY" ),
            misdemeanors = data.filter(subArr => subArr[1] == "MISDEMEANOR");

    function sorter(arr){
      const newarr = [];

      for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        newarr[arr[i][0][0] - 1] = arr[i];
      }

      return newarr[0] || newarr[1] || newarr[2];
    }

    return felonies.length > 0 ? sorter(felonies) : sorter(misdemeanors);
}
```

- For starters I'd recommend the es6 filter array method to separate felonies and misdemeanors, this method returns an array with elements that meet a conditional, in our case "FELONY" or "MISDEMEANOR"
- The next thing I wrote was a custom sorter that takes in an array, loops through it and by using the number we find that'll be the index assignment in our newarr, so if we come across "1st" we break it down to 1 then we subtract -1 from it and place it in the 0 index of newarr. What's happening is that we are taking advantage of the number it already holds to place it, in its respective *"place"*.
- last statement of our custom sorter is to return the 1st item it comes across and that'll be dependent of the data we give it, for instance [ ["3rd", "MISDEMEANOR"], ["2nd", "MISDEMEANOR"]] would not have an item at position 0 but it would at position 1 and so the || statement is perfect for the job
- Lastly, a ternary operation checks to see if there are any felonies by checking against the length, if so return the result of sorter for felonies, otherwise we return the result for misdemeanors

Comment: `For starters a good es6 practice would be to use the filter array` - 
Where is this "good es6 practice" mentioned by the way? Please use the word "recommended" instead if you strongly feel so.

Comment: you're right it's merely a recommendation of my part, however it's a good practice in the way that it reduces the need to write a conditional when looking to loop through an array only to retrieve back certain elements by using conditional statements.